# Parameterized types in Linked Lists

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

I have a data structure and I need to compare data to previous elements that occurred at the same time.
Something like:

```
dataStruct{
long startTime;
long endTime;
long data;
}
```

part of my implementation involves adding these elements to a linked list and comparing data between nodes that exist at overlapping times. Do I need a parameterized type or can I add dataStructures to the list and access their members by the dot operator. Something like:

```
    dataStructure data = new DataStructure(time, time2, data);
    dataStructure moreData = new DataStructure(time3, time4, data2);

    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

    list.add(data);

    if(list.peek().endTime > moreData.startTime){
    moreData.data = list.peek().data + moreData.data;
    list.pop();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a parametrized type.

```
LinkedList<DataStructure> data = new LinkedList<DataStructure>();
```

This way, you can get a `DataStructure` instead of an `Object` out of the `LinkedList`.

Otherwise, you're using the raw form of the `LinkedList` class which deals with `Object`s.  It is possible to cast what you get out of the list as a `DataStructure`, and that would work.  But using generics with a parametrized type is preferred; raw types and casting is the old, pre-Java 5 way of operating on collections.

Whether you can access the members directly depends on whether the code that creates and uses these `DataStructure`s is in the same package, because you have (default) package visibility on the members of `DataStructure`.

Generally you will want encapsulation on your `DataStructure` type, with `private` member variables and `public` "getter" and "setter" methods that access those values.  Then any code can use `DataStructure` with access to the values.